# jQuery how to get select change work in multiple form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, select

I got this script from here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#choose').change(function(event) {
        $.post('select-ajax.php', { 
  selected: $('#choose').val()
  },
            function(data) {
                $('#update').html(data);
            }
        );            
    }); 
});
 <form id='form'>
    <div id="update"></div>
    <select name='selected' id="choose">
        <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test3</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

and i want to use it with multi ple form and also want it change only in that form , can anybody help me to make the code just like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#choose').change(function(event) {
        $.post('select-ajax.php', { 
  selected: $('#choose').val()
  },
            function(data) {
                $('#update').html(data);
            }
        );            
    }); 
});
 <form id='form'>
    <div id="update"></div>
    <select name='selected' id="choose">
        <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test3</option>
    </select>
    </form>
 <form id='form'>
    <div id="update"></div>
    <select name='selected' id="choose">
        <option value="1">111</option>
        <option value="2">222</option>
        <option value="3">333</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it from using IDs, which must be unique to using classes, like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="update"></div>
    <select name='selected' class="choose">
```

Then make your script find the elements relatively, like this:

```
$('.choose').change(function(event) {
  var update = $(this).prev();
  $.post('select-ajax.php', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    update.html(data);
  });            
});
```

I'm also using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the `<form>` here, you can leave that out and use `{ selected: $(this).value() }` to pass *only* the `<select>`'s value.  This approach works for any number of forms in the page.

Comment: @Choo - Welcome :) Be sure to accept answers on this and future questions via the check-mark beside the one that resolved your issue best, it helps the next person coming from google and "closes out" the question :)

Answer (score 0):

`id` is unique to the page and should only be used once per element.

for your situation first thing would to replace id's with classes and change the jQuery accordingly.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.choose').change(function(event) {
        $.post('select-ajax.php', { 
  selected: $(this).val()
  },
            function(data) {
                $(this).prev('.update').html(data);
            }
        );            
    }); 
});
 <form class='form' name="form1">
    <div class="update"></div>
    <select name='selected1' class="choose">
        <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test3</option>
    </select>
    </form>
 <form class='form' name="form2">
    <div class="update"></div>
    <select name='selected2' class="choose">
        <option value="1">111</option>
        <option value="2">222</option>
        <option value="3">333</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the `name` attribute is not unique on a page, or even within a `<form>`.  Also your callback won't update anything, since `this` would refer to the `ajax` object jQuery uses for the request, *not* the `<select>` that changed.

Comment: Those aren't the only exceptions, there aren't exceptions because there is no rule...you can use a name a dozen times if you want, even in the same form.

Comment: @Nick: fair enough, best practice then?

Comment: Nope...it's not that either, a form may have 20 of any item and that's perfectly fine, it's even common in bulk data entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same `id` (`choose`, `form`) for multiple elements. You need to use different id names per element per page. Once you do that, you can modify your code like this:

```
$('#choose, #choose2').change(function(){
  // your code to handle two select boxes.
});
```

Where `choose` and `choose2` are supposed to be the ids of your select boxes.

Note the comma in the selector; it is used to add more selector expressions/elements to the wrapped set. In your case, it represents two select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

the `id` attribute should only be used once in your page, its a unique id for an element, if you want to select multiple elements you can use the following method.

```
<form id="search_users">....</form>
<form id="search_blogs">....</form>

$("#search_users,#search_blogs").change(...);
```